# How to get real path on openshift tomcat 7(JBoss EWS 2.0) server

Tags: java, openshift

In my wicket application I have method to get path when I want to save some files:

```
public static String getFilesPath() {
    String path = WebApplication.get().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "/";

    System.out.println(WebApplication.get().getServletContext()
            .getRealPath(RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getContextPath())
            + " 1");
    System.out.println(WebApplication.get().getServletContext().getContextPath() + " 2");
    System.out.println(WebApplication.get().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + " 3");


    return path;
}
```

when I am testing this on localhost jetty server it works OK but when I deploy my application to openshift tomcat 7 server I just get null:

```
null 1
 2
null 3
```

is there some other way how to get path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java application is running a little differently on OpenShift than it is locally on your development system (in memory), so the `getRealPath()` method is not going to work correctly.
You should save files into your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR (~/app-root/data), which you can get in java using `System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR")`.  This also makes sure that your files are stored in a persistent location that will not be deleted/recreated when you redeploy your application.  For instance, your ~/app-root/repo directory gets recreated whenever you deploy an application, so don't save uploaded files there.